# Any security concerns from pointers in ReSTFUL URLS

Tags: security, rest

Say you have a restful URL, where you have a pointer to an important object in the URL, such as:

```
/api/shoppingcart/{shoppingcartid}/
```

Or

```
/api/creditcard/{creditcardid}/
```

Is that not very dangerous? For example, suppose a hacker sees the URL, they could just change it very easily and post on up to your site?

If I go this approach,how can I be sure there is nothing risky going to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Use ssl for sensitive transactions, and yes it's better to do post if you want data not to be visible in url

Comment: Authorization and authentication are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dangerous at all if you apply authentication and authorization to each HTTP action on all of your URIs, and as long as your URIs don't contain information that benefits hackers (such as actual credit card numbers).

Comment: But what if someone changes the pointer and sends the same request?

Comment: Then they'd better present valid credentials for that new request, and it's up to your system's API server implementation to enforce auth at a highly granular URI level.